# ModelMapper: how to map this json to Java?

Tags: java, json, gson, modelmapper

I am attempting to use ModelMapper to map the following json as explained here http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/gson-integration/ but I am getting a NullPointerException and I can't figure what is wrong. Any tips please?

```
{"a": "aaa", "b": [{"c": "ccc"}]}   

public class Foo {
  private String a;
  private ArrayList<Bar> b;
}



public class Bar {
  private String c;
}

ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.getConfiguration().addValueReader(new JsonElementValueReader());
JsonElement responseElement = new JsonParser().parse(json);
Foo foo = mapper.map(responseElement, Foo.class);
```

Comment: Where do you get a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: When posting "why do I get this error" type questions, you need (at a minimum) to post the full stack trace, and indicate which line in your code is throwing the exception.  Even better would be to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This is the stack trace I get: https://gist.github.com/dabd/1b84bab88144ff6bc873#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: With that JSON, `String json = "{\"a\": \"aaa\", \"b\": [{\"c\": \"ccc\"}]}";` and that code, things run just fine. Perhaps you could post a complete test that is failing?

Comment: I made an even simpler Json and switched to Jackson. Here is a complete test that fails: https://gist.github.com/dabd/e912418bd8105f3bd7ec#file-gistfile1-java.  This is the pom I am using https://gist.github.com/dabd/cee26e64cf6c7df6bf5d#file-gistfile1-xml.  Stack trace: https://gist.github.com/dabd/4d82fa1ce12d4291c22d#file-gistfile1-txt. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @dmz73 I misunderstood where the `NullPointerException` was coming from in your question. This seems like a bug. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review of what you meant and your comment in the question, this is very likely a bug in their implementation. The javadoc for `ValueReader` claims

> Returns all member names for the source object, else `null` if the source has no members.

However, the only code that uses this method, `PropertyInfoSetResolver#resolveAccessors(...)`, does not check for the existence of `null`. Member names in JSON only make sense for objects, but, here, you have a JSON array. That's why it fails.

As far as I can tell, the code doesn't check for `null` nor for `source` types that don't have members. I consider this a bug. The error is easily reproducible from the sample example by replacing any of the fields (and the corresponding JSON) with array types. You might want to contact the developer or change libraries.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the cause. I noticed this when I traced the execution of the library. Hopefully the author will fix this small bug.